# Get validation error messages without saving

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

```
Post
  :belongs_to :user

User
  :has_many :posts
```

In my signup workflow they draft a Post first, then on the next page enter their User information to signup.

```
# intermediate step, validate that Post is valid before moving on to User creation
# posts_controller:

@post = Post.new(params[:post])
if @post.valid?
  # go on to create User
else
  render 'new'
end
```

BUT! @post error messages aren't created since I'm not saving the @post model I'm just checking for `.valid?`. How do I create the error messages without saving?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly you want to get the errors without saving the model?

That is exactly what is happening. `@post.valid?`

will return true or false depending on whether there are any errors. If there are errors. they will be added to `@post.errors`hash.

In the situation where you want to save just call `@post.save`
It will return true if successfully saved or false if errors are present while populating `@post.errors` in the process

Comment: You are correct. I wasn't showing @post.errors properly. Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

According to [documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#valid-and-invalid), once you've called `#valid?` or `#invalid?` on a record, `#errors` is populated.

Comment: For people coming across this question: the corollary is that if you try working with `#errors` before calling `#valid?` (or `#save`, etc), then you might not get any `errors` even though `valid?` is `false`.